# Trivial answer conversion

Tags: support, convert-to-comment

I've noticed that on some Stack Exchange sites (like Super User), if I post a short answer I get "Trivial answer automatically converted to comment". However, on other sites (like Android Enthusiasts) this never happens.

Why is it so?

Comment: There's no such thing as a trivial Android answer... ;)

Comment: The convert-to-comment might depend on site size before it's turned on.

Comment: I think part of "trivial" requires a link to another stack exchange post (so you're not earning rep for "hey the answer's here (link)")

Comment: @BenBrocka it could be that I didn't check